# Pandas Segmentation Fault while using "replace"

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing a scraper bot which **works efficiently both on my windows laptop and on my linux Virtual machine**, but I get a segmentation fault on a **Google cloud instance**.
The problem is that a specific piece of code is getting segmentation fault error, while it does the same things of other functions

## Segmentation fault log

```
    Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault
Current thread 0x00007f247ea04e80 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 126 in _broadcast_to
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 182 in broadcast_to
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6 in broadcast_to
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 463 in split_and_operate
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2637 in convert
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 800 in <listcomp>
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 800 in replace
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 2691 in replace
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 442 in apply
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 589 in replace
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6738 in replace
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/venv3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4172 in replace
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/database.py", line 130 in preprocess_DF_articoli
  File "/home/vateranboy/Amazon_bot/database.py", line 52 in __init__
  File "main_test.py", line 244 in monitoraggio_articoli
  File "main_test.py", line 361 in <module>
```

## Code that segmentation fault is referred to

I'm simply reading some data from a gsheet and replacing "VERO" and "FALSO" with *true* and *false*.

The second line (so the second ".replace") is the **line 130** reported in the segmentation fault log:

```
 def preprocess_DF_articoli(self):
        self.DF_foglio_articoli[["pubblicare"]] = self.DF_foglio_articoli[["pubblicare"]].replace("FALSE", False)
        self.DF_foglio_articoli[["pubblicare"]] = self.DF_foglio_articoli[["pubblicare"]].replace("TRUE", True)
        i = 0
        for index, row in self.DF_foglio_articoli.iterrows():
            link_img = str(row["immagine"])
            if "drive.google.com" in link_img:
                self.DF_foglio_articoli["immagine"].iloc[i] = get_img_visualizzabile(link_img)
            i += 1
        custom_logging.log("debug", "Preprocessing articoli completato.")
```

the strange thing, as I mentioned, is that this process is also repeated for other sheets, using other methods, and they work perfectly.

### Content of the sheet

The sheet contains just 9 rows x 7 columns which are:

- id
- link of the article on my website
- title of the article
- some text
- link of the image
- "pubblicare" ( = to publish)
- section of the website

I'm using python 3.7 on VM with linux and on Cloud instance, 3.6 on Windows; my Google instance is **n1-highcpu-2 (2 vCPU, 1,8 GB RAM)**

(I only provided this code because it seems to be the direct cause, but I can provide more if necessary.)

I don't know if changing the specs of the instance might help, but the program requires few memory and cpu.
Hope someone can help me, I'm really going mad.

## EDIT - solved (more or less)

I replaced that piece of code without involving the "replace" method like this:

```
def preprocess_DF_articoli(self):
    i = 0
    for index, row in self.DF_foglio_articoli.iterrows():
        if row["pubblicare"] == "FALSE":
            self.DF_foglio_articoli["pubblicare"].iloc[i] = False
        elif row["pubblicare"] == "TRUE":
            self.DF_foglio_articoli["pubblicare"].iloc[i] = True
        link_img = str(row["immagine"])
        if "drive.google.com" in link_img:
            self.DF_foglio_articoli["immagine"].iloc[i] = get_img_visualizzabile(link_img)
        i += 1
    custom_logging.log("debug", "Preprocessing articoli completato.")
```

The code now work **but the problem with "replace" still remain**; the conclusion is that the code linked to *replace* function, which, if I'm not wrong, uses **numpy** and so some C or C++ implementation, has some bug not easy to debug given the fact that the segmentation fault occurred on Google Cloud instances but not on local OS, infact i tried to:

- give more RAM to the instance
- give more cpu
- creating a new instance with Ubuntu and not Debian

and nothing helped.

Comment: Which line in the code snippet is number 244?

Comment: @mac13k in order you have "monitoraggio_articoli" which calls (line 244) the consuctor of my db class (based on Gsheet), which calls (line 52) the method which i reported, and then the line 130 in "preprocess_DF_articoli" is the second one in the code (so, the second "replace"). Sorry, I'll update the question.